# Change Image Displayed When Website Is Displayed On Facebook?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

As you know, when you share a Link/Website on Facebook... Facebook scrapes the image(s) off of the link to give the "story" a more visible representation of what you are sharing. Seeing as the background for Facebook is WHITE. The images that I want to display are white, so, it doesn't really work out.

I am curious as to ask if there is a way to change the Default Image for your Website once shared on Facebook. Is there a code in PHP? Or jQuery? HTML? Anything? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These meta tags should do the trick:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="url to image" />
<meta property="og:title" content="title of the page" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="name of the site" />
```